# JavaScript Attribute update within loop, resetting all previous value with last value

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

```
[{
"_id": "5987496838099514948b4a1c",
"availableServices": [{
    "_id": "598750d238099514948b4a33",
    "serviceType": {
        "_id": "59874b3438099514948b4a20",
        "uniqueIdentifier": "AC",
    },
    "serviceSubTypes": [{
        "_id": "598750d238099514948b4a34",
        "serviceSubType": {
            "_id": "59874b5638099514948b4a21",
            "displaySubTypeName": "DRY SERVICE",
            "minimumServiceCost": "399",
            "zonalMinimumServiceCost": [{
                "_id": "59874b5638099514948b4a22",
                "minimumServiceCost": "399",
                "zone": "5987496838099514948b4a1c",
                "providerPrice": [{
                    "_id": "59a3007ee8c1cb276c042e64",
                    "minimumServiceCost": "400",
                    "provider": "598752c6265bbd162009ef35"
                }]
            }, {
                "_id": "599da2247910831a3c9b90aa",
                "minimumServiceCost": "399",
                "zone": "599da2247910831a3c9b90a8",
                "providerPrice": []
            }],
        },
        "providerAtServiceSubTypeLevel": [{
            "companyName": "TEST2",
            "calculatedMinServicePrice" : "0" 
        }, {
            "companyName": "TEST1",
            "calculatedMinServicePrice": "0"

        }]
    }, {
        "_id": "598750d238099514948b4a35",
        "serviceSubType": {
            "_id": "59874b6738099514948b4a23",
            "displaySubTypeName": "WET SERVICE",
            "minimumServiceCost": "399",
            "zonalMinimumServiceCost": [{
                "_id": "59874b6738099514948b4a24",
                "minimumServiceCost": "399",
                "zone": "5987496838099514948b4a1c",
                "providerPrice": [{
                    "_id": "59a3076ee8c1cb276c042e66",
                    "minimumServiceCost": "412",
                    "provider": "598752c6265bbd162009ef35"
                }]
            }, {
                "_id": "599da2247910831a3c9b90ab",
                "minimumServiceCost": "399",
                "zone": "599da2247910831a3c9b90a8",
                "providerPrice": []
            }]

        },
        "providerAtServiceSubTypeLevel": [{
            "_id": "598759c3232d9920884e103a",
            "companyName": "TEST2",
            "calculatedMinServicePrice" : "0"  
        }, {
            "_id": "598752c6265bbd162009ef35",
            "companyName": "TEST1",
            "calculatedMinServicePrice" : "0"   

             }],

        }]
    }
```

}]

**My execution logic is :**

a. loop through availableServices

b. Find each Service Sub Types

c. Calculate Maximum Service price depend on minimumServiceCost , zonalMinimumServiceCost.minimumServiceCost and providerPrice.minimumServiceCost

d. update providerAtServiceSubTypeLevel.calculatedMinServicePrice depend on above calculated price (if providerPrice present then that will be considered during updation)

e. This will continue for all available Service Sub Types

**Problem Statement**

a. During the loop and updation of  providerAtServiceSubTypeLevel.calculatedMinServicePrice all previous elements are updating
with last value

**Just to mimic the problem here is the code**

```
for(var a=0;    a < zonedetails[0].availableServices.length; a++){

for(var b=0;    b < zonedetails[0].availableServices[a].serviceSubTypes.length; b++){

        for(var c=0;    c < zonedetails[0].availableServices[a].serviceSubTypes[b].providerAtServiceSubTypeLevel.length; c++){

                        console.log(" a  >> " + a + " b  >> " + b + " c  >> " + c);
                        zonedetails[0].availableServices[a].serviceSubTypes[b].providerAtServiceSubTypeLevel[c].calculatedMinServicePrice = a+b+c;
                        console.log("Change in first element >> " + zonedetails[0].availableServices[0].serviceSubTypes[0].providerAtServiceSubTypeLevel[0].calculatedMinServicePrice);

        }
}
```

}

**And here is the output**

a  >> 0 b  >> 0 c  >> 0
Change in first element >> 0

a  >> 0 b  >> 0 c  >> 1
Change in first element >> 0

a  >> 0 b  >> 1 c  >> 0
Change in first element >> 1

a  >> 0 b  >> 1 c  >> 1
Change in first element >> 1

a  >> 0 b  >> 2 c  >> 0
Change in first element >> 2

a  >> 0 b  >> 2 c  >> 1
Change in first element >> 2

a  >> 1 b  >> 0 c  >> 0
Change in first element >> 2

**I am really stuck here and not able to find any clue or solution to resolve it. any help is requested. Thanks to all in advance **

Comment: The code you provide doesn't give the same results you show here.  I only have 4 loops (a always = 0, b = 0 for 2 loops, 1 for 2 loops, c = 0 for 2 loops, c for 1 for 2 loops), in addition the JSON needed some editing to work (there were two missing ] characters near the end.  Most importantly, the "change in first element" was 0 for every loop.  Can you please revise your example to be consistent with what you're posting?

Comment: Yes .. i have reduced the main json to make it handy .. I am posing the same for reference.

Comment: But i am not allowed to edit the question now .. how to send the full JSON object

Comment: Fork or update this fiddle?  https://jsfiddle.net/jbreadner/sr120o9h/

Comment: Thanks .. i have updated it ..One thing i missed to mention .. this is a Mongo DB document retrived using mongoose. and i am operating on that object ..

Comment: Sorry, I think it's been updated only for you, perhaps?  Can you use the Fork functionality on jsfiddle to publish a new version?

Comment: here is the new fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/9otm476c/1/            Please consider this is a mongoose object (document retrieved from mongo db using mongoose )

Comment: I can see this, thanks.  Mongoose will only return a JSON object, so if the one in the the JSFiddle is correct, then the whole Mongoose thing is irrelevant.  However, I see that the code in the JSFiddle also does not modify the top level object, the "Change in first element" always returns 0.  Can you please re-evaluate whether the JSFiddle code is what you expect, or re-state your problem so it's clear what we're trying to help with?

Comment: Is your logic acting directly on the object returned by Mongoose?  Perhaps you have to save it to a variable first, then act on it?  I'm actually not super familiar with Mongoose, I've just gone through a few tutorials.